# How can I download a Pi image with Tensorflow Lite already installed?

Tags: raspbian, pi-zero-w

This whole nonsense of cross-compiling is nuts.  Can I just download an image of Raspbian for my Pi Zero W with tensorflow lite already installed?

Comment: TensorFlow release 1.9 can be installed from pre-built binaries using Python’s pip package system! https://www.raspberrypi.org/magpi/tensorflow-ai-raspberry-pi/

Comment: Thank you for the help :). I’m actually looking to use tensorflow LITE though.